# Powershell Export-CSV Error - "The process cannot access the file \\xxx\hhh\fff\report.csv because it is being used by another process

Tags: powershell, export-csv, distributed-filesystem

Help please - I have a script to report all DFS folder targets and will check the path status but I'm getting a random export-csv error "*The process cannot access the file \xxx\hhh\fff\report.csv because it is being used by another  process.*". It doesn't happen to each of the loop, script will run w/o an error for few loops then I will get the message. I tried adding Start-Sleep from 1-10 secods but still getting the same error.

Script below:

```
  cls
$Report = "\\server1\DFSReport"
$Date = (Get-Date -format "MMddyyyy")
$Tab = [char]9

$Roots = Get-DfsnRoot -Path 'ABC.com\data'

ForEach ($Root in $Roots) {
        Write-Host
        Write-Host $Tab Enumarating $Root.Path -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $Dirs = Get-DfsnFolder -Path "$($Root.Path)\*" | Where-Object { ($_.Path -notlike '*.DFSFolderLink*') -and ($_.Path -notlike '*test*') }
        Write-Host $Tab Found $DIRs.Count Folder Targets -ForegroundColor DarkCyan

        ForEach ($DIR in $DIRs) {

            $Targets = Get-DfsnFolderTarget -Path $DIR.Path | Select-Object State, Path, NamespacePath, TargetPath, ReferralPriorityClass, ReferralPriorityRank 
            
            ForEach ($Target in $Targets) {
                
                $TF = @{
                        $True  = 'Accessible'
                        $False = 'NOT Accessible'
                       }
                $DFSN = Test-Path $Target.NamespacePath
                    Write-Host
                    Write-Host $Tab $Tab Checking DFSN Path - $Target.NamespacePath - $TF[($DFSN)] -ForegroundColor Cyan
                $NativePath = Test-Path $Target.TargetPath
                    Write-Host $Tab $Tab Checking DFSN Target Path - $Target.TargetPath - $TF[($NativePath)] -ForegroundColor DarkYellow

                $Prop = [ordered]@{
                                 'DFS State' = $Target.State
                                 'NamespacePath' = $Target.NamespacePath
                                 'NamespacePath Status' = $TF[($DFSN)]
                                 'TargetPath' = $Target.TargetPath
                                 'TargetPath Status' = $TF($NativePath)]
                                 'ReferralPriorityClass' = $Target.ReferralPriorityClass
                                 'ReferralPriorityRank' = $Target.ReferralPriorityRank
                                 }

                $Obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Prop
                Write-Output $Obj | Export-Csv -Path "$Report\DSFN-Report-$Date.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 4
            }
        }
}
```

Added Start-Sleep, maybe someone can help what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Is your script the only script that writes to the csv or is there some other application/scheduled task also accessing it? As aside, instead of `Write-Output $Obj | Export-Csv ...` just feed the object itself to the Export-Csv cmdlet: `$Obj | Export-Csv`

Comment: No other app is writing/accessing it. Thank You, I will try that.

Comment: You do not have permission to read the file.  If you are an admin try running PS by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Generally speaking I would recommend capturing the output and writing it all to a file at once rather than appending to the file in a loop causing PowerShell to open and close the file over and over.

Comment: $Obj | Export-Csv did it however I still need to suspend it for 2 seconds but at least it's not skipping any of the report now to the csv file. Thank you very much, really appreciate it.

Comment: Yep I do run all my PS as Admin - I know I know not recommended :) but last thing I need to worry about.

Comment: Yep, I think I need to rewrite and save it to an array instead of appending it to csv for each of the loops. The only reason why I am avoiding this method in the past is because depending on how big the data is, it will eat up my memory but in this case, only few hundreds of rows so it's not so bad.